# SQL left joins returning weird IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running this SQL query in a SQL Server database,

```
SELECT staff_list.id AS staff_id, 
       staff_list.status,  
       core_teams.workbase, 
       core_teams.service_user, 
       core_teams.staff_name,  
       core_teams.role, 
       service_users.id AS su_id  
FROM staff_list  
     LEFT JOIN core_teams   
       ON staff_list.workbase = core_teams.workbase  
     LEFT JOIN service_users
       ON service_users.name = core_teams.service_user
WHERE staff_list.status <> 'Left' 
     AND staff_list.status <> 'Name Changed';
```

The join and results are being returned,  however the attribute `staff_id` is being repeated multiple times over many rows for users that have relevance to the `staff_id`. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: There is more than one match on the tables you are joining to, for the criteria you have provided on the join.

Comment: You probably do an m:n-join instead of m:1

Comment: Not at all.  That is how SQL works.

Comment: as others have pointed out it is because of more than 1 match.  I would suspect the issue is how you are joining service users via core_teams because core_teams is likely inclusive of many users.  For specific help on an issue like this you should post sample data from each table and your desired result otherwise we have no way of helping you achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a link between staff_list and core_teams.

```
SELECT staff_list.id AS staff_id, staff_list.status,  
core_teams.workbase, core_teams.service_user, core_teams.staff_name,  
core_teams.role, service_users.id AS su_id  
FROM staff_list  
LEFT JOIN core_teams   
 ON staff_list.workbase = core_teams.workbase  
     --missing link
     AND staff_list.name = core_teams.staff_name
LEFT JOIN service_users
 ON service_users.name = core_teams.service_user   
WHERE staff_list.status <> 'Left' 
 AND staff_list.status <> 'Name Changed';
```